# JSP and pagination links

Tags: jsp, pagination

I want to display a pagination link in this way: current page and 3 links forward and 3 links backward.

Obviously i don't want to display the links for negative pages or for pages after the last one.

So in my pagination.jsp i have the following:
`param.pages` is the total number of pages
without the `<c:if test="${page < param.pages} ">` stuff, i display the links correctly but with no check on pages after param.pages. With the c:if, i display nothing, I think it's because the test does not recognize *page*

```
    <c:forEach begin="${currentPage + 1 }" end="${currentPage + 3}" var="page">
            <c:if test="${page < param.pages} ">
            <li><a
                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${param.currentURL }/<c:out value="${page }"/>">
<c:out value="${page }"/> </a></li>
            </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
```

Which is the best way to procede?

Comment: You can have a look at [this demo](https://github.com/BranislavLazic/spring-thymeleaf-pagination). I used Thymeleaf. But you'll figure it out. Logic to calculate what links will be displayed is in `Pager` class.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it, using only JSP tags, don't know if it's the best solution, but it works, i'll write it down if anyone need it.

In my pagination.jsp

```
<c:set var="maxLink" value="4"></c:set> // it's the number of links you want before and after the current one

// this part is to avoid to have negative values in the forEach cycle for the previous links
<c:set var="bottomLimit" value="${param.currentPage - maxLink }"></c:set>

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${bottomLimit <= 0 }">
                <c:set var="begin" value="1"></c:set>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:set var="begin" value="${bottomLimit }"></c:set>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

<c:forEach begin="${begin }" end="${param.currentPage -1}"
            var="pageBefore">

            <li><a
                href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${param.currentURL }/<c:out value="${pageBefore }"/>"><c:out
                        value="${pageBefore }" /> </a></li>

        </c:forEach>

// link to the currentPage
<li class="active"><a
            href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${param.currentURL }/${param.currentPage}">${param.currentPage }</a></li>

//Link to the next pages, that ends at the last page
<c:set var="end" value="${param.currentPage + maxLink }"></c:set>
<c:forEach begin="${param.currentPage + 1 }" end="${end}" var="page">
            <c:if test="${page <= param.pages}">
                <li><a
                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${param.currentURL }/<c:out value="${page }"/>"><c:out
                            value="${page }" /> </a></li>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
```